# How to draw Flutter Widgets off-screen

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for a solution to draw a Flutter Widget tree in a separate graphic pipeline that will never be displayed on the screen. I want to be able to define the width/height constraints to any size regardless of the display.
The goal is to get a png image of this Widget that is not dependent on the device, to send it to a printer. I know it's possible to use `RepaintBundary` to build an image but that's only for something displayed on the screen.

I tested something like this, with no luck:

```dart
Future<void> capture(BuildContext context, Widget widget) async {
  final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 200, 200);

  final root = OffscreenPainter(
      size: Size(200, 200),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 200, height: 200),
        child: widget,
      ));

  final ro = root.createRenderObject(context);

  final el = root.createElement();
  // el.activate();
  el.attachRenderObject(ro);
  final o = PipelineOwner();

  // ro.attach(o);
  o.rootNode = ro;
  ro.scheduleInitialLayout();
  final rootLayer = OffsetLayer();
  rootLayer.attach(o);

  ro.scheduleInitialPaint(rootLayer);

  el.updateChildren();
  ro.layout(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: rect.width, maxHeight: rect.height));

  o.flushLayout();
  o.flushCompositingBits();
  o.flushPaint();
  final im = await ro.toImage();
  final bd = await im.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  final f = File('image.png');
  f.writeAsBytesSync(bd.buffer.asUint8List());
  print('saved to ${f.absolute}');
}

class OffscreenPainter extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  /// Creates a widget that isolates repaints.
  const OffscreenPainter({Key key, Widget child, @required this.size})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final Size size;

  @override
  RenderOffscreenPainter createRenderObject(BuildContext context) =>
      RenderOffscreenPainter(size);
}

class RenderOffscreenPainter extends RenderRepaintBoundary {
  RenderOffscreenPainter(this._size);

  final Size _size;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    if (child != null) {
      child.layout(BoxConstraints.tight(_size));
      size = child.size;
    } else {
      size = _size;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you try to use `Overlays`?  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html

Comment: Overlay is still a widget, it can't be drawn off-screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) Widget to push your widget off-screen. According to the docs, Transform.translate moves the widget *before* it's painted.

In this example, I added an Icon to the bottom navigation bar and shifted it down. It doesn't show but I can still access the RepaintBoundary.

```
Transform.translate(
  offset: Offset(0,200),
  child: RepaintBoundary(
    key: iconKey,
    child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.star),
        onPressed: () {
          // Do something
        }),
  ),
),
```